# Ordenar por custom meta box un custom post type - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un custom post type llamado "eventos". En él, tengo un custom meta box llamado fecha (que es el día, mes y año en el ocurrirá el evento).

El problema es que quiero que crear un nuevo obj WP_QUERY, pueda ordernarlo por la fecha que introduje en el custom meta box, de más recientes, a más lejanos, y que aquellos que ya ocurrieron, que no se muestren.

Sé que existe el order_by (lo coloque abajo) pero entre las opciones no encontré ninguno que haga referencia a un custom meta box.

¿Qué podría hacer en este caso?

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') :1;            
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'eventos', 
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('content-eventos');
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Perdon, me confi de post

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo más o menos así:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') :1;            
$hoy = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+2 hours'));
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'eventos',
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_key' => 'start_date', 
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'start_date',
    'value' => $hoy,
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
  ))
));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que agreagar el campo **meta_key** y opcional el arreglo **meta_query** con la condición de filtro.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') :1;            
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'eventos', 
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'campo_metabox',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'campo_metabox',
            'value' => 'valor',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'tipo_de_variable'
        )
    ),
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        get_template_part('content-eventos');
    } 
}
```

El **tipo_de_variable** puede ser cualquiera de los campos que se usan en la tabla.